# can't define a function - based lookup table

Tags: javascript, json, function, lookup-tables

I am trying to define a function based lookup table - an array of objects, each contains a function (existing function, not arrow function) and a string. I have tryied:

```js
let lookup_table = [{'foo', bar}, {'abc', def}];
(.....)
function bar(command){(..)}
function def(command){(..)}
```

another (and more prefered) soulotion will be to refer to the function by a string index, somethig like that

```js
lookup_table['foo']('abc'); //=bar('abc')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set an array for `lookup_table` when all you really need is a single object.

Syntax error also using comma as separator between property and value in your objects

The following example works

```js
function bar(command){console.log('Called bar() , command =', command)}
function def(command){console.log('Called def() , command =', command)}

let lookup_table = {'foo': bar,'abc': def};

lookup_table['foo']('abc');
lookup_table['abc']('123');
```